# Jenkins docker permission

Tags: postgresql, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

On a Ubuntu server, I'm running jenkins docker container. For testing purpose, in my jenkinsfile of my project, I must **run a postgres server**.
I'm trying to build a container postegres docker in my steps.

However, I can't do it, I get permission errors :

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock:
>   Get
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/containers/json?filters=%7B%22name%22%3A%7B%22vpx_postgres%22%3Atrue%7D%7D:
>   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Here my jenkins file below. The stage "Database creation" is failling.

```
def message = "";
def author = "";

def getLastCommitMessage = {
    message = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git log -1 --pretty=%B').trim()
}

def getGitAuthor = {
    def commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD')
    author = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "git --no-pager show -s --format='%an' ${commit}").trim()
}

pipeline {
    agent {
        docker { image 'starefossen/ruby-node' }
    }
    stages {
       stage('Database creation') {
                    steps {
                        sh 'docker ps -f name=project_postgres -q | xargs --no-run-if-empty docker container stop'
                        sh 'docker container ls -a -fname=project_postgres -q | xargs -r docker container rm'
                        sh 'docker pull postgres'
                        sh 'docker run --name project_postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -p 5432:5432 -d postgres'
                    }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                  getLastCommitMessage()
                  getGitAuthor()
                }
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test bundle install --jobs 3'
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test yarn install'
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rails db:migrate'
                sh 'RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rspec -f documentation'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
          rocketSend channel: 'project-x-ci', emoji: ':x:', message: "Build failed - Commit : '${message}' by ${author}", rawMessage: true
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the issue is from the jenkins docker ? Here the docker-compose.yml :

```
version: '2'

services:
  jenkins-server:
    build: ./ 
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    volumes:
      - /home/xero/jenkins/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    environment:
      JENKINS_USER: jenkins
      JENKINS_URL: "http://10.0.1.66:8080/"
      DOCKER_SOCKET: /var/run/docker.sock
      DOCKER_GROUP: dockerhost
      DOCKER_HOST: unix:///var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
    dns:
      - 10.0.1.1
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM jenkinsci/jenkins:latest
USER root

COPY ["entrypoint.sh", "/"]

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install sudo && \
    chmod 755 /entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash","-c","./entrypoint.sh"]
```

And my entrypoint.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -S ${DOCKER_SOCKET} ]; then
    DOCKER_GID=$(stat -c '%g' ${DOCKER_SOCKET})
    groupadd -for -g ${DOCKER_GID} ${DOCKER_GROUP}
    usermod -aG ${DOCKER_GROUP} ${JENKINS_USER}
fi

exec sudo -E -H -u jenkins bash -c /usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh
```

**IMPORTANT :**

***HOST(ubuntu) -> JENKINS(docker) -> POSTGRES(docker)***

In my jenkins docker container, docker is available, I have no problem. The issue is when I build a project in jenkins from an jenkinsfile.

So the JENKINS container, cannot create other container (here, the POSTGRES container)

Answer (score 3):

Figure out the user that is used to run `jenkins` and add that user to the `docker` group.

This should take care of the permissions issue.

You can add a user to the docker group using `sudo usermod -aG docker <jenkins-user-name>`.

Info of why [this is needed](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/):

> The docker daemon binds to a Unix socket instead of a TCP port. By
>   default that Unix socket is owned by the user root and other users can
>   only access it using sudo. The docker daemon always runs as the root
>   user.
>
> If you don’t want to use sudo when you use the docker command, create
>   a Unix group called docker and add users to it. When the docker daemon
>   starts, it makes the ownership of the Unix socket read/writable by the
>   docker group.

Comment: where do I have to run this ? on the host machine ?

Comment: yes, run this on the host machine. Do ensure you substitute the correct user that is being run by the jenkins process

Comment: If you decide to do this, make sure you understand the security implications: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/178886/20774

Comment: I do not have a jenkins user in my host machine =/, the thing is that I run jenkins on my host machine, and then then the jenkins container must create docker container. And in my jenkins container, I don't have docker group (but I have a dockerhost). I edited my post with docker-compose.yml